# Product Url Key not working rewrite and category say url key specified store already exists

Tags: magento2, product, category, url-rewrite

The **product url keys not working**, sometimes they do suddenly it goes to the original url like:
https://www.takoda.shop/nl/catalog/product/view/id/5/s/dog-tag-halsketting-messing/category/5/

and not as I prefer that is stays like this:
https://www.takoda.shop/nl/dog-tag-halsketting-messing.html

Where is that all about?

*Also*

When I want to change the content of the dutch store view of a category it say: *URL key for specified store already exists.*

So there is obviously something wrong here

Anybody got any experience with solution this sort?

Thanks a lot in advance

> The url keys for the products are alright again when I export all
>   products and import them all, but that doesn't seem to be the way it
>   has to work, is it ? In terms of emergency it can work like that until
>   the real solution appears

[image]

Comment: It might be an indexing issue. Did you setup the magento crons?

Comment: @kevin-ramen thanks for you comment, I have put my cron jobs print screen picture, am I missing something?

Comment: Seems good. In system->index management, are you indexers "ready" or "index required" ?

Comment: Concerning the url already exists, I know there was a bug in magento 1.x where you could not have the same url in two different stores. That is the urls must be unique across all stores. I don't know if  it is the case in magento 2 as well.

Comment: @kervin-ramen Yes the indexers are ready, I understand but the url is different for every store view ...