# Product url displaying category-ID and product-ID

Tags: magento-2.1, url-rewrite, product-urls

Few Product urls are displaying with category and product id but few products are working fine.

I want to keep all URL like: http://localhost/magento2/test-product not 
like below http://localhost/magento2/catalog/product/view/id/1234/category/12/

My issue is same like [link 1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/137230/29175) and [link 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/159783/29175) but its not sorting out. I tried [mage2 solution](https://mage2.pro/t/topic/312) but it also didnt help.

> This is specific for each category. Product-URLs of one category are
>   working well but other category have issues. That means
>   issue can be of category level not a product level.

Looking for solution.

Answer (score 2):

**Steps to configuration to remove the category-ID and product-ID**

1. Enable product url by categories in Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Search Engine Optimization > Use Categories Path for Product URLs select **No**